# How to integrate ListView with FolderListModel using QML?

Tags: qt, qml

I am developing a file browser interface using QML. However, I find I cannot click any folder and the list covered the top button. I don't know what I did wrongly.

I used ListView and FolderListModel during the development. And I intend to make the interface as below and works like a file browser

The expected interface:
[image]

**Source Code:**

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.1
import Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 2.1
import QtMultimedia 5.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import Qt.labs.platform 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    property int index: 0
    property bool isActive: true

    SwipeView {
        id: swipeView
        anchors.fill: parent
        currentIndex: tabBar.currentIndex

        Page1 {
            Rectangle {
                id:root;
                state:"hidden";
                color: "#212126";

                property string folderPathName: "file:///C:/";
                property bool rootPath:false;
                signal message(string msg);
                property int lineHeight: 90;
                signal selectedFolder(string folderPath);

                Button{
                    id:topLine;
                    text: "...";
                    width: root.width;
                    height: root.lineHeight;

                    onClicked: {
                        if (folderModel.parentFolder != ""){
                            root.folderPathName = folderModel.parentFolder;
                        }
                        else{
                            root.state = "hidden";
                        }
                    }
                }

                ListView{
                    id:listFileView;
                    anchors{
                        bottom: rectangleButton.top;
                        bottomMargin: 4;
                        right: root.right;
                        rightMargin: 0;
                        left: root.left;
                        leftMargin: 0;
                        top: topLine.bottom;
                        topMargin: 0;
                    }
                    clip:true;

                    delegate:Button{
                        text: fileName;
                        height:root.lineHeight;
                        width:root.width;

                        onClicked: {
                            if(folderModel.isFolder(index)){
                                root.folderPathName = folderModel.get(index, "fileURL");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    model: FolderListModel{
                        id:folderModel;
                        objectName: "folderModel";
                        showDirs: true;
                        showFiles: true;
                        showDirsFirst: true;
                        nameFilters: ["*.mp3", "*.flac"];
                        folder:root.folderPathName;
                    }
                }

                  Rectangle {
                    id: rectangleButton;
                    height: 20;
                    color: "#212126";
                    anchors{
                        left: root.left;
                        leftMargin: 0;
                        right: root.right;
                        rightMargin: 0;
                        bottom: root.bottom;
                        bottomMargin: 0;
                    }

                    Rectangle{
                        id:rectWhiteLine;
                        anchors{
                            left:parent.left;
                            right: parent.right;
                            top:parent.top;
                        }
                        height: 2;
                        color:"white";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Page {

        }
    }

    footer: TabBar {
        id: tabBar
        currentIndex: swipeView.currentIndex
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("Main")
        }
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("View")
        }
    }
}
```

After changing anchors{ bottom: rectangleButton.top; bottomMargin: 4; right: root.right; rightMargin: 0; left: root.left; leftMargin: 0; top: topLine.bottom; topMargin: 0; } to width: 200; height: 600, the interface turns to be below:

[image]

The folders cannot be clicked and they are not correctly aligned.

Comment: As documentation suggests "The value must be a file: or qrc: URL, or a relative URL." Try `file:///C:/`. Not on windows so I can't guarantee what backslashes and path to write after `file:///`

Comment: I tried, but it still doesn't show any files.

Comment: `anchors{
                        bottom: rectangleButton.top;
                        bottomMargin: 4;
                        right: root.right;
                        rightMargin: 0;
                        left: root.left;
                        leftMargin: 0;
                        top: topLine.bottom;
                        topMargin: 0;
                    }` Change this to something like `width: 200; height: 600`

Comment: It is better now but seems not aligned correctly. I have updated the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this example would be of any use to you.
I have added "back" button that goes up one folder, and buttons that represent folders inside `ListView` are colored orange.

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle {
        id: mainRect
        x: 20
        y: 20
        width: 300
        height: 450
        border.color: "black"
        radius: 30
        ListView {
            y: 30
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height - 60
            clip: true
            model: FolderListModel {
                id: folderListModel
                showDirsFirst: true
//                nameFilters: ["*.mp3", "*.flac"]
            }

            delegate: Button {
                width: parent.width
                height: 50
                text: fileName
                onClicked: {
                    if (fileIsDir) {
                        folderListModel.folder = fileURL
                    }
                }
                background: Rectangle {
                    color: fileIsDir ? "orange" : "gray"
                    border.color: "black"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Button {
        anchors.left: mainRect.right
        anchors.leftMargin: 5
        text: "back"
        onClicked: folderListModel.folder = folderListModel.parentFolder
    }
}
```

[image: preview]

To get clickable top area with "..." I would add Text there and Mouse Area to handle clicks:

```
Text {
    width: parent.width
    height: 30
    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
    text: "..."
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: folderListModel.folder = folderListModel.parentFolder
    }
}
```

Add this code inside `mainRect` i.e. after line `radius: 30`.

Comment: Hi, thank you in advanced, can the back button embed at the top of the listview like my expected interface? I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Added an example how to make top of the listview clickable. You could also look into ListView header and maybe implement something clickable in there.